# Troubleshoot "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Tags: permissions

I recently changed the database table prefix from wp_ to something else, for security reasons.

Since then, I am unable to reach /wp-admin, instead receiving

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I read [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82520/troubleshooting-a-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-e), and I renamed `wp_user_roles` to `myprefix_user_roles`.

This did not resolve the problem, even after clearing my browser cache and cookies.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you do this on a live site with themes and plugins installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the db prefix on a WordPress installation requires more than simply changing the prefix on the tables. There are also options that use the db prefix in the options tables. You'll need to update them as well. Specifically the `wp_user_capabilties` and the `wp_user_level` keys in the `{db_prefix}_options` table.

See the following tutorial for further information:

> #### [How to Change the WordPress Database Prefix to Improve Security](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-wordpress-database-prefix-to-improve-security/)
>
> The smartest way you can protect your database is by changing the database prefix which is really easy to do on a site that you are setting up. But it takes a few steps to change the WordPress database prefix properly for your established site without completely messing it up.

**Example SQL Queries**

```
UPDATE new_usermeta
SET meta_key = REPLACE(meta_key,'old_','new_');

UPDATE new_options
SET option_name = REPLACE(option_name,'old_','new_');
```

Comment: I found `wp_user_level` but not `wp_user_capabilties`.  Interestingly, I didn't find `_user_capabilties` in any of my Wordpress site databases, all running WP3.5.1.  After updating the 2 `wp_user_level` entries, the issue remains.

Comment: I didn't find `wp_user_capabilities` because I was using a standard PHPMyAdmin search, which searches the value, and not the key name.  When I ran the SQL query on the wpbeginners.com site, I found the `wp_user_capability` keys.